# Java Map issue in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC application(RestFul), The controller has a method/API which returns

```
Map<Long, List<Long>>.
```

I need to call the above API in another web application. To do this I have written a client program which will internally call
the API and return the data.

But instead of sending

```
Map<Long, List<Long>>
```

it always sends data in

```
Map<String, List<String>>.
```

Can't I send directly

```
Map<Long, List<Long>>
```

If I create a BO/TO(Java Bean) and which has a property of type Map>
then I am able to get the data in proper format

Below is the code snippet.

```
public Map<Long, List<Long>> get(Long sourceId){

Map<Long, List<Long>> map = null;

// codes to perform operation and putting data into map.

return map;
}
```

Can you please suggest what is the issue ?

Comment: We need the actual code where "it's sending". Most likely, the issue is that since you're using Generics and the type parameter (`Long`) is not present at runtime, Spring doesn't know to work its magic and auto-translate the `String` into a `Long`.

Answer (score 0):

Anything sent over the wire is a String ... but your code picking up the response should convert it to long. Well it would if it were a spring-mvc controller with the correct method signature.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Javascript? Try to use the javascript parseFloat method on your JSON data